# Implementing JavaScript/JQuery on Image Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, picture-library

I am looking for implementing solution using JavaScript/jQuery in Image Library (SP 2013) to view image with one color and after clicking on it, it should show up all the different colors.
For example I have 15 calculator images of different color. And I would like to keep black as default color before I clicks to view all other colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a naming scheme `[basename]_[color].png` for all Library images.

Use **CSR - Client-Side-Rendering** on a View, or **Display Templates** when you use the Search Query WebPart

- The JavaScript will loop over all (search)Items (*thats what CSR or DT code does by default*)
- return empty HTML for non [default] images to display only the default images
  record these non-black images in a [basename] array
- return HTML+JavaScript for [default] images to:

  - display [black] image
  - onclick: display all the images in the associated array

This is all basic JavaScript CSR/DT code

The onclick part is where your UX-design creativity is required, in the simplest form you don't return blank HTML for non-default images but hide them with `display:none`

Comment: Hey Danny, Thanks for the reply. I am not proficient in CSR, have implemented few samples. It would be great if you can look at this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can point you in a direction but I can not do your job... otherwise it would not be your job, and your pay would end up in my bankaccount

Answer (score 0):

I have got an idea, just try it up. Hope it will works

1. Create a Image library
2. Add two fields to it **Front Image** -> *Single Line of Text*, **Link to Front Image** -> *Single line of text*. We will be using these fields to query items.
3. Add the black image of calculator and set the value of the above fields. **Front Image** as *blackcalculator* and **Link to Front Image** as *blackcalculator*. The *blackcalculator* is a token to find the group of images of same family.
4. Now add the remaining 14 calculator images of different colors. For all the images set the properties **Front Image** as *empty/blank* and **Link to Front Image** as *blackcalculator*.
5. Create a new page and add a Javascript to it.
6. The Javascript will access the image library and fetch the items which has **Front Image** field is set with a proper value and not null or empty.
7. Build a HTML in the below format using the Javascript and embed it in the page content. The token 'blackcalculator' is the value of **Front Image** which will be used as a token.
8. The token 'blackcalculator' should be used as a token to query all the other images for which the **Link to Front Image** field is set as *blackcalculator*.
9. Open a page using modal dialog, which will display all the images that belongs to the *blackcalculator* family.

Check it out and let me know if it helps you.

HTML Format of front image in the page:

```
<a href="#" onclick="OpenModalDialog('blackcalculator')"> <img src="/ImageLibrary/calculatorblack.jpg" /> </a>
```